# How do i resolve promises properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

How do I make sure all promises are resolved properly? Here even after the execution of the function some statements are still getting printed(the ones where I have added comments). I feel getAllRecords is not completing promises properly. Where am I going wrong?

```
const getAllRecords = async (offset = 0) => { 
  return fetchRecord(offset, 10).then((resp) => { 
    console.log("Called fetchRecord") 
    if (resp.status === 'success') {
       let responseData = resp.data 
       if (responseData.length === 0 { 
         return ({ status: 'success' }) 
       } 
      return processData(responseData).then((updateResp) => { 
        if (updateResp.status === 'success') { 
           offset += 10 
           return getAllRecords(offset) 
         } else { 
           return ({ status: 'error' }) 
       }
       }).catch(err => { 
         return ({ status: 'error' }) 
       })
      } else { 
        return ({ status: 'error' }) 
      } 
  }).catch(err => { 
    return ({ status: 'error' }) 
  }) 
} 


const mainFunc = async () => { 
  console.log('Inside mainFunc') 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    return firestore.getAllCities() 
      .then(async (cities) => { 
        return getAllRecords().then(getAllRecordsResponse => { 
          console.log("Called getAllRecords") // 
          if (getAllRecordsResponse.status === 'success') { 
             return getAllRecordsResponse 
           } else { 
             return reject({ status: 'error' }) 
           } 
        }).then((getAllRecordsResponse) => {
             let updateArray = []
             console.log("Updating firestore db") 
             for (const city of cities) { 
                updateArray.push(firebaseDao.updatecityDoc(city)) 
             } 
             return Promise.allSettled(updateArray).then((responseArr) => { 
               let errorArr = [] 
               responseArr.map((item) => 
                 item.status === 'rejected' ? errorArr.push(item.reason) : null 
               ) 
               if (!errorArr.length > 0) { 
                 console.log("done processing") //
                 return resolve({ status: 'success' }) 
               } else { 
                 return resolve({ status: 'error' }) 
               } 
         }) 
      }).catch((err) => { 
        return resolve({ status: 'error' }) 
      }) 
    }).catch((err) => { 
      return resolve({ status: 'error' }) 
    }) 
  }) 
}
```

I am trying to fetch records from some other place in fetchRecord and processing the extracted data in processData. getAllRecords is a recursion because we cant get all the data at once, only 10 records can be extracted, so I am extracting the records until I get an empty response.

Where is the promise not getting handled properly is what I am not sure about. Am I missing out something here?

Is there a way to use promises only rather than async/await?

Comment: You must use the `await` keyword

Comment: Don't mix `async`/`await` with `.then` and don't use `new Promise` when inside you have other promise-aware code, it makes the code very hard to follow and causes bugs. Try to use only `async`/`await`. Also, you are throwing away all the errors you may get and just return a generic error, this will make it quite hard to understand why something is failing when it is failing.

Comment: @CherryDT I'll add appropriate error messages. The problem I am facing is that the execution is happening successfully but those statements with comments(//) are getting executed after the function call is completed. Rather than async/await could promises itself be used to resolve the issue?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: "*Is there a way to use promises only rather than async/await?*" - uh, you are not using `await` anywhere?!

Answer (score 2):

The following is imo an implementation which achieves the same ends but with better practices, and solves your problem of un`await`ed promises! Note that I spoofed all the functions you referenced but didn't include in your question, so you can actually run this code:

```js
const getAllRecords = async function*(offset = 0, limit = 10) {
  
  // Yields records from `fetchRecord`, one at a time
  // Records are selected in batches of size `limit`
  
  while (true) {
    // Select latest batch; halt if no items are returned
    const { data: items } = await fetchRecord(offset, limit);    
    if (!items.length) return;
    
    for (const item of items) yield item;

    // Increment the offset; will loop again
    offset += limit;
  }
  
};

const mainFunc = async () => {

  const cities = await firestore.getAllCities();
  
  // Loop through all records yielded by `getAllRecords`; each will result
  // in an "update promise" which we store in an array:
  const updatePromises = [];
  for await (const record of getAllRecords())
    for (const city of cities)
      // TODO: Ignoring `record`??
      updatePromises.push(firebaseDoc.updatecityDoc(city));
  
  // If we want to return all errors which occurred instead of just the
  // first, we need to do some manual error handling - all `updatePromises`
  // have a `.catch` applied, which stores the error
  const settled = await Promise.allSettled(updatePromises);
  
  // A final resulting error has an "errors" property attached to it,
  // exposing the full set of errors which occurred
  const errors = settled.filter(item => item.status === 'rejected');
  if (errors.length) throw Object.assign(Error('Some updates failed'), { errors });
  
  // No return value upon success

};

// Spoofed objects, to make this script runnable:
const firestore = {
  getAllCities: async () => [ 'toronto', 'new york', 'los angeles', 'tokyo' ]
};
const firebaseDoc = {
  updatecityDoc: async (...args) => console.log('Updating city doc; args:', args)
};
const spoofedRecords = 'a'.repeat(30).split('').map((v, i) => ({ recordNum: i }));
const fetchRecord = async (offset, limit) => ({
  data: spoofedRecords.slice(offset, offset + limit)
});

mainFunc()
  .then(() => console.log('Completed successfully'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Encountered fatal error', err));
```

Some practices which make this code, imo, better:

- Never use return values to indicate errors! Always implement functions such that if they return a value, it indicates success. Always assume that if a function returns a value, it executed successfully. If you want to signify that a function failed, throw an Error - never return something like `{ status: 'failed' }`! This will make your code much leaner, robust, and easier to debug!
- A generator (`function*`) is used to perform repetitive batch selections
- I removed `.then` in many cases where its use made the code less unmaintainable
- Some syntax errors are fixed; "firebaseDao" typo is fixed
- Overall structure makes it easier to avoid un`await`ed promises

This new format raises a question: why are the records returned from `getAllRecords` ignored? That can't be right - shouldn't they factor into `firebaseDoc.updatecityDoc(...)`?

Comment: I got give a +1 purely for using generators for pagination. One minor nitpick: your answer makes it seem like `.then` is "bad" *in general*, rather than OP's use being not great *in this particular case*. There are actually cases where the `.then` can be less verbose and more elegant.

Comment: @JaredSmith totally agree with your critique, I updated hoping to imply that `.then` has valid use-cases!

Comment: Instead of the ugly `promise.catch(err => errors.push(err))`, I would recommend to use `Promise.allSettled` if you need all individual errors

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new Error`, not just `Error`?

Comment: @Bergi ty for telling me about `allSettled`! :)

Comment: @CherryDT `new Error('...')` and `Error('...')` have identical results! But maybe for consistency it could make sense to always use `new`

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

**Don't nest asynchronous code.** That's the rule-of-thumb for avoiding most mistakes.

## Thorough Version:

It's frequently the case that you want to do something asynchronous based on the result of another asynchronous operation, and then do something else. There are two right ways to do that, and a lot of wrong ones. So lets say we have two Promise-returning functions `f` and `g` and we need to pass the result of `f` to `g`.

## Wrong

Nest the `.then` handlers like in your sample code:

```
function doTheThing() {
  f().then((fResult) => {
    g(fResult).then((gResult) => {
      console.log(gResult)
    })
  })
}
```

### Why It's Bad

Say instead of 2 steps it's 10, and each depends on the previous result. Now you're at a potentially 40 space indent before you get to the code that actually does anything useful, and you've recreated the dreaded [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) Promises were supposed to protect us from just with much worse performance from all the wrappers and extra allocations. Also what about error handling? You can only `.catch` at the individual Promise level, every `.then` in the chain is a potential UnhandledRejectionError.

## Wrong

Mix `.then` with `async/await`:

```
function doTheThing() {
  f().then(async (fResult) => {
    const gResult = await g(fResult)
    console.log(gResult)
  })
}
```

### Why It's Bad

It's obviously sub-optimal compared to just marking `doTheThing` as `async` and using `await` to get the result of calling `f` in the first place.

## Wrong

Resolving an outer Promise when the inner Promise resolves. Say we want to *return* a Promise of `gResult` from `doTheThing`:

```
function doTheThing() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    f().then((fResult) => {
      g(fResult).then((gResult) => {
        resolve(gResult)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

### Why It's Bad

This is the fabled [Promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) and in addition to the problems outlined in that Q&A you can no longer defer error handling to the caller.

## Right

```
function doTheThing() {
  return f().then(g).catch(console.error)
}
```

If you need to do more intermediate work than just call `g` with the result of `f` you can do it like this:

```
function doTheThing() {
  return f()
    .then((fResult) => {
      // do intermediate work
      return g(fResult)
    })
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

This takes advantage of Promises auto-flattening: when we return a Promise from `.then` we get a `Promise<T>` rather than a `Promise<Promise<T>>`. We can even tack another `.then`:

```
function doTheThing() {
  return f()
    .then((fResult) => {
      // do intermediate work
      return g(fResult)
    })
    .then((gResult) => {
      // do something
    })
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

Another benefit of this approach is that the single `.catch` at the end will catch *all* the Promise rejections anywhere in the chain of `.then`s, which you **cannot** do if you nest the calls rather than chain them!

## Also Right

```
async doTheThing() {
  const fResult = await f()
  const gResult = await g(fResult)
  // do stuff
  return gResult
}
```

Simple. Gets the job done. Can be combined with `try/catch` for easy-peasy error handling:

```
async doTheThing() {
  try {
    const fResult = await f()
    const gResult = await g(fResult)
    // do stuff
    return gResult
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

For an idea of what these principles applied to your code might look like, see [this other answer that refactored your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76774253/3757232).

Comment: Note that in the async/await code, you're no longer passing the result of `f` to `g`. Minor nit :).

Comment: "*You can only .catch at the individual Promise level*" - not true. You can easily put a single `.catch()` at the end - this is why promises are so much better than callbacks, they are [chainable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) (or as you put it, flattening). You only need to [nest if you need a previous result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) in scope (as you pointed out). As long as you `return` each of the nested promises, this pattern works just fine - even if it looks ugly.

Comment: @Bergi I meant more that if you nest rather than chain you can't use a `.catch` on the inner to handle an error in the outer function (or vice versa). I do use a single `.catch` on the chained `.then`s in the correct version. Agree with you about the ugliness of situations where you need multiple things in scope, one alternative (as I'm sure you know) is to return `Promise.all`ed arrays of the things you need to avoid the nesting.

Comment: Ah, I see, you meant that while nesting one cannot do what `.then(…).then(…).catch(…).then(…)` would achieve: handling errors in the middle, only from previous promises/handlers but not the following handlers. Admittedly, one cannot nicely do that with `try`/`catch` either (while still passing on a result).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to spot, but the root of your problem is the [use of the `Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). While you are trying to handle all errors, you made the mistake to think that

```
         return reject({ status: 'error' })
```

completes the `mainFunc`. But it doesn't - it returns `undefined` only from the current `.then()` handler, then it executes the next `.then()` handler with `undefined` as the argument, continuing execution even after your promise is already rejected.

You can fix the mistake by not chaining `.then(…).then(…)` here, instead using a single function:

```
…
    return getAllRecords().then(getAllRecordsResponse => { 
      console.log("Called getAllRecords")
      if (getAllRecordsResponse.status !== 'success') { 
        return reject({ status: 'error' }) 
      } else {
//    ^^^^^^^^
        let updateArray = []
        console.log("Updating firestore db") 
        for (const city of cities) { 
          updateArray.push(firebaseDao.updatecityDoc(city)) 
        } 
        return Promise.allSettled(updateArray).then(…);
      }
    });
…
```

---

However, that doesn't improve your code by much. Your error handling is all over the place, with lots of duplicated code, and you should get rid of the `new Promise`. Also if you want to use `.then()` instead of `await`, there is no reason to declare your functions as `async`.

For the error handling, keep errors as rejections and only handle and transform them into a result object in the very end.

```
function getAllRecords(offset = 0) { 
  return fetchRecord(offset, 10).then(resp => { 
    const responseData = resp.data;
    if (responseData.length === 0 { 
      return;
    } 
    return processData(responseData).then(updateResp => {
      offset += 10;
      return getAllRecords(offset);
    });
  });
} 


function mainFunc() {
  console.log('Inside mainFunc') 
  return firestore.getAllCities().then(cities => { 
    return getAllRecords().then(getAllRecordsResponse => { 
      console.log("Called getAllRecords")
      const updateArray = []
      console.log("Updating firestore db") 
      for (const city of cities) { 
        updateArray.push(firebaseDao.updatecityDoc(city)) 
      } 
      return Promise.allSettled(updateArray);
    });
  }).then(responseArr => { 
    const errorArr = responseArr.filter(item =>
      item.status === 'rejected'
    ).map(item =>
      item.reason
    );
    if (!errorArr.length) {
      console.log("done processing");
      return { status: 'success' };
    } else { 
      return { status: 'error' };
    }
  }, err => { 
    return { status: 'error' };
  });
}
```

While this code is already much simpler, I would recommend to use `async`/`await` syntax as demonstrated in the other two answers. You no longer need to use recursion for `getAllRecords`, and you won't have as much nesting, which greatly eases refactoring.